# Json not getting data from list

Tags: json

I am having a problem with reading json data. I have tried a few methods but came up short. Any help is welcome. Here is the code:

Its corrected with the whole file now.

```
 "gallery": {
          "106x100": [
            "106x100-0.jpeg",
            "106x100-1.jpeg",
            "106x100-2.jpeg",
            "106x100-3.jpeg",
            "106x100-4.jpeg",
            "106x100-5.jpeg",
            "106x100-6.jpeg",
            "106x100-7.jpeg",
            "106x100-8.jpeg",
            "106x100-9.jpeg",
            "106x100-10.jpeg",
            "106x100-11.jpeg",
            "106x100-12.jpeg",
            "106x100-13.jpeg",
            "106x100-14.jpeg",
            "106x100-15.jpeg",
            "106x100-16.jpeg"
          ],
            "190x100": [
            "190x100-0.jpeg",
            "190x100-1.jpeg",
            "190x100-2.jpeg",
            "190x100-3.jpeg",
            "190x100-4.jpeg",
            "190x100-5.jpeg",
            "190x100-6.jpeg",
            "190x100-7.jpeg",
            "190x100-8.jpeg",
            "190x100-9.jpeg",
            "190x100-10.jpeg",
            "190x100-11.jpeg",
            "190x100-12.jpeg",
            "190x100-13.jpeg",
            "190x100-14.jpeg",
            "190x100-15.jpeg",
            "190x100-16.jpeg"
          ]
        },
      },
```

Comment: What language do you use to read a json?

Comment: I am using java

Comment: @zomlaaa95 :  Share the code that you wrote, so we can tell you what to correct.

Comment: You have a trailing comma and a missing opening curly brace. See Kinshuk's answer.

Comment: If the input file you're listing is incorrect, then nothing will help. So you need to provide correct input and code if you like help.

Answer (score 2):

Your json's format is wrong.

Here is the correct format:

```
    {"190x100": [
            "190x100-0.jpeg",
            "190x100-1.jpeg",
            "190x100-2.jpeg",
            "190x100-3.jpeg",
            "190x100-4.jpeg",
            "190x100-5.jpeg",
            "190x100-6.jpeg",
            "190x100-7.jpeg",
            "190x100-8.jpeg",
            "190x100-9.jpeg",
            "190x100-10.jpeg",
            "190x100-11.jpeg",
            "190x100-12.jpeg",
            "190x100-13.jpeg",
            "190x100-14.jpeg",
            "190x100-15.jpeg",
            "190x100-16.jpeg"
          ]}
```

PS: Read that you are using java. You can then try this:

```
   String jsonString = "{"+json+"}"; //pass json here if you are getting it in that format.
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("gallery");
    System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
```

Again the format is wrong. Here is the format:

```
 {"gallery": {
          "106x100": [
            "106x100-0.jpeg",
            "106x100-1.jpeg",
            "106x100-2.jpeg",
            "106x100-3.jpeg",
            "106x100-4.jpeg",
            "106x100-5.jpeg",
            "106x100-6.jpeg",
            "106x100-7.jpeg",
            "106x100-8.jpeg",
            "106x100-9.jpeg",
            "106x100-10.jpeg",
            "106x100-11.jpeg",
            "106x100-12.jpeg",
            "106x100-13.jpeg",
            "106x100-14.jpeg",
            "106x100-15.jpeg",
            "106x100-16.jpeg"
          ],
            "190x100": [
            "190x100-0.jpeg",
            "190x100-1.jpeg",
            "190x100-2.jpeg",
            "190x100-3.jpeg",
            "190x100-4.jpeg",
            "190x100-5.jpeg",
            "190x100-6.jpeg",
            "190x100-7.jpeg",
            "190x100-8.jpeg",
            "190x100-9.jpeg",
            "190x100-10.jpeg",
            "190x100-11.jpeg",
            "190x100-12.jpeg",
            "190x100-13.jpeg",
            "190x100-14.jpeg",
            "190x100-15.jpeg",
            "190x100-16.jpeg"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: @zomlaaa95 Please post the entire json not the piece.

Comment: I need to get every item in that 190 x 100 object. I dont need it as a one string

Comment: @zomlaaa95 You have to loop through it. Then you will get the key and then you have to loop within it using `getJSONArray("106x100")`

Comment: Yes i understand that, but i dont know the syntax

Comment: @zomlaaa95 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124731/discussion-between-kinshuk-lahiri-and-zomlaaa95).